# How to solve this logic puzzle in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

1. A,B,C,D,E,F is one list.
2. C is before E
3. A is after F
4. E is not in fifth
5. There are two between E and  A
6. After B is E, B is adjacent to E

Which one is the fourth ?

Comment: you can translate all constraints using nth1 and usual arithmetic on list indexes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you write the code for me? @CapelliC

Comment: You need to show some effort toward a solution and ask a more specific question. What have you tried? This website is not a place to come and ask others to do your homework for you.

Comment: @lurker Finally I solved the problem by myself

Comment: @MinglangJing that's great!

Comment: @lurker: Is this a [tag:zebra-puzzle]? Not sure.

Comment: @false maybe it's a "simplified zebra puzzle" since the items have no attributes other than position.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem by myself

```
before(A,B) :- A<B.
after(A,B) :- A>B.
notInFifth(A) :- A \= 5.
adjacent(A,B) :- abs(A - B) =:= 1.
separatedByTwo(A,B) :- abs(A - B) =:= 2.


solution(A,B,C,D,E,F) :-
    permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6], [A,B,C,D,E,F]),
    notInFifth(E),
    separatedByTwo(D,A),
    adjacent(B,E),
    before(C,E),
    before(F,A),
    before(E,B).
```

list is : c e b d f a

Comment: A few suggested improvements... Use CLP(FD) for the arithmetic, such as `A #< B`, `A #> B`, `abs(A-B) #= 1`, etc. Also instead of `findall(X0,permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6],X0),L), member([A,B,C,D,E,F],L)`, you only need `permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6], [A,B,C,D,E,F])` in its place. Or better, instead of `permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6], [A,B,C,D,E,F])`, use CLP(FD) and use `[A,B,C,D,E,F] ins 1..6, all_different([A,B,C,D,E,F])`. To use CLP(FD) you'll need `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` if you're using SWI Prolog.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try

Comment: Even if you choose not to use CLP(FD), just replacing `findall(X0,permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6],X0),L), member([A,B,C,D,E,F],L)` with simply `permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6], [A,B,C,D,E,F])` would be an improvement.